# Create Kafka Topic using vertx

Tags: apache-kafka, vert.x

How can we create producer for different topics using vert.x. Vert.x zanox module did some pretty job but seems it was limited to one topic. There is no way to send messages to desired topic. It sticks to one topic which we gave at config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Zanox module (like me) I just deploy one module per topic that I need to produce to, passing in a different configuration file (with appropriate topic name).

Not the most efficient approach I agree, but short of writing your own Kafka module/integration this is the only option available.